# Alfresco default work flow template changing

Tags: alfresco

I am running alfresco 5.0.a and I want to modify the default activitiAdhoc template to set the title and description of the task. I run an activti flow when a file is added to a directory via script. My script is.

```
var workflow = actions.create("start-workflow");
workflow.parameters.workflowName = "activiti$activitiAdhoc";
workflow.parameters["bpm:sendEMailNotifications"] = true;
workflow.parameters["wf:notifyMe"] = true;
workflow.parameters["wf:workflowDescription"] = "A workflow task has been  completed. ";
workflow.parameters["bpm:assignee"] = people.getPerson("admin"); 
workflow.parameters["wf:workflowTitle"] = "Please generate a cover letter for";
var futureDate = new Date();
futureDate.setDate(futureDate.getDate() + 7);
workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowDueDate"] = futureDate; 
workflow.execute(document);
```

Also i would like to change the template subject email. It currently says "You have been assigned a task" I have changed this in the workflow template as well as 
/opt/alfresco-5.0.a/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco/messages/notification-service.properties

I have set bootstrap-context.xml file to redeploy for the ad hoc default. Restarted and still never see a change in the wf-email.ftl or when i run.

How do I modify this? No documentation I have found talks about how to change this.

Comment: Can you change the template file in the data dictionary?

Comment: I did manage to get some of it changed in that file. But really id like to set the title of the email. Also set the workflow title. But the template does not recognize the parameter workflowTitle. It appears not possible.

Answer (score 3):

To change the subject of the notification email sent from a workflow, I did the following:

Copied the notification-service.properties file into my project, and changed the value of the assigned-task field.  The location I placed that file in my project was \src\main\amp\config\alfresco\module\\messages

I also added a spring bean to my project, which points to that file. I put mine in \src\main\amp\config\alfresco\module\\context\service-context.xml.  (This bean overrides the one provided by alfresco in /repository/config/alfresco/notification-services-context.xml)

```
<bean id="notificationServiceResourceBundles" class="org.alfresco.i18n.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent">
   <property name="resourceBundles">
      <list>
         <value>alfresco.module.${project.artifactId}.messages.notification-service</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Lost some XML in posting.  The bean to be replaced is bean id="notificationServiceResourceBundles" class="org.alfresco.i18n.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent" and the text at the end of the answer above is new value of it.

Comment: Thank you :) I'm new to posting on here!

Comment: Do you know how to make the subject value dynamic ? How do I pass a parameter of the workfow like task title?

Comment: @Fjordo  To set the subject dynamically, you could override the WorkflowNotificationsUtils.java class.

Add a class org.alfresco.repo.workflowMyWorkflowNotificationUtils.java into the project. Have it extend Alfresco's WorkflowNotificationUtils class:
`public class MyWorkflowNotificationUtils extends WorkflowNotificationUtils {
...`
Find the code for WorkflowNotificationUtils (e.g. in Alfresco's github repository) and in MyWorkflowNotificationUtils, override any methods from  WorkflowNotificationUtils where the subject is set.

Also add a spring bean for the new class.

Comment: To add the bean for the new class (into service-context.xml or other appropriate location):

`<!-- Override of WorkflowNotificationUtils bean -->
<bean id="workflowNotification" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.MyWorkflowNotificationUtils">
<property name="workflowService" ref="workflowServiceImpl"/>
<property name="nodeService" ref="NodeService"/>
<property name="notificationService" ref="NotificationService"/>
<!-- Any other services your class requires -->
</bean>`